# What is operator "?" Like "Decimal?"

Tags: c#

Hi there I don't know what is this `"?"` operator.
Can anyone explain this for me?

> public virtual decimal? abc {get; set;}

Comment: it means abc is nullable.. it can hold null value or decimal value

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shorthand for `Nullable<Decimal>`. it can be null, you can check `.HasValue` to see if it is null or you can get `.Value` for the value itself if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: `.HasValue` is a property and not a method.

Comment: @Sunil corrected, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `T?` is shorthand for `Nullable<T>`, where `T` is a value type. You can use any of the syntax.

2 properties are useful in this case. `.HasValue` and `.Value`

```
if(abc.HasValue) a = abc.Value;
if(abc != null) a = abc.Value;
a = abc != null ? abc.Value : 0;
```

You can also assign null to them.

```
decimal? abc = null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I give a scenario where this `nullable` type is useful. for example in your case abc, it can hold values like 4.6, 7.9, 9.45 etc.

If you are thinking  of initializing value of abc to `undefined` or `null` , that is not possible if you define abc as normal decimal like this

```
public decimal abc { get; set;}
```

so if you define abc as nullable type like

```
public decimal? abc { get; set;}
```

you can assign null to `abc` like below

```
abc= null;
```

or decimal value

```
abc = 4.567
```

if you want check whether abc has non- null value there is property to check that

`abc.HasValue()`  this will return  true or false

and  to get the actual decimal value out of `abc`  you can try like this

```
if(abc.HasValue())    
var enteredValue = abc.Value
```

I hope this helps

Comment: `.HasValue` is a property and not a method

Comment: Thanks for your help